# Where is mods-available on Freeradius on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

When installing Freeradius on Centos, I get the mods-available folder in here, which contains an sql file:

```
/etc/raddb/mods-available/sql
```

When installing Freeradius on Ubuntu, it is named differently.

```
/etc/freeradius
```

However, there is no `mods-available` to be found. There are only a `modules` folder, which doesn't contain `sql` either.

I have googled a lot without any luck on this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mods-available/` comes by default with FreeRADIUS 3.x (Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty, or Debian Stretch).

In earlier versions `modules/` contained mostly the same files, but wasn't as consistent. In the 2.x series (which your Ubuntu version has), the SQL configuration lives in `/etc/freeradius/sql.conf` and some of the settings are slightly different.

Comment: Thanks, I should have tagged it as Ubuntu 16.04. But yes you were right, that was because of version 2.0.  The latest version is consistent.